# I am unable to execute a bootstrap modal after 5 seconds to pop up on the page using only javascript.

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

** I am new to javascript and willing to learn it on my own interest . I am unable to execute a bootstrap modal after 5 seconds to pop up on the page using setTimeout in javascript. I dont need it in Jquery. Please someone assist me on this **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>Task_1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container main_div">

  <div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please click to watch the video again..</p>
        <div class="popup_img">
          <img src="images/alert.png">
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">


setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('show');
}, 12000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change 12000 to 5000.

Comment: Yes, above code is working fine. Change the timeout as per your requirement.

Comment: I want the script in Js not in Jquery. Need to kno how to access the target model using JS

Answer (score 1):

Wrap around the `$(function () {})` and change `12000` to `5000`.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('show');
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container main_div">
  <div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please click to watch the video again..</p>
          <div class="popup_img">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x75?text=alert" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```